# SQLiteDatabase Query in android

Tags: android, sql, database

Am having a table **card** with colums **id,name, content,status, date.**

i want to take **id,name,content** condition is **status <= cards.STATUS** also have to **sort it by date**

How i have to do this.
am doing like,

```
private Cursor c;

String[] cols = { id,name, content };
c = cardsDB.query(CARDS_TABLE_NAME, cols, "status <=" + Card.STATUS, null, null, null, "date desc");

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                CardArray.add(new Card(c.getInt(0), c.getInt(1), c.getString(2)));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
```

Comment: Exists one component for FireFox to check your queries for SqlLite [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/ca/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the complicated query , its better to use raw query not query method.

This is an example of how to implement a raw query:

```
String query= "Select id,name ,content  from CARDS_TABLE_NAME Where status <= ? date desc";
Cursor c= database.rawQuery(query, new String[]{Card.STATUS});
```